# I manually added a field to frontend article submission form but it does NOT save the data. What is wrong?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform

I created a frontend form override for article submission `tmpl/form/edit.php` and added the following field as plain HTML

```
<input type="text" name="jform[attribs][videourl]" id="jform_attribs_videourl" value="" />
```

I expected the data to be passed to the `__content > attribs` table but it just returns empty. Is it that fields must be served from xml only?